# continuously store 'get' and store data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gps

I need to continuously make this http.get request from an API that sends back location data

So i tried writing a basic get reuest to check if the data is coming through, and it is, the problem is I need it in a continuous loop every second the gps device sends data.

```
http.get(_url2, res =>{
    let body='';

        res.on("data", data =>{
            body+=data;
        })
     res.on("end",()=>{
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        gpsData.push(body.data);
        console.log('gpsData Array : ',gpsData)

    })
})
```

I get this logged out to the console, 
   `$ node server3.js
    gpsData Array :  [ [ { imei: '86851212020143921',
      device_info: 0,
      device_info_new: 0,
      seconds: 0,
      gps_time: 1548760740,
      sys_time: 1548760744,
      heart_time: 1548760744,
      server_time: 1548760748,
      lng: 33.756899,
      lat: -13.973598,
      course: 160,
      speed: 7,
      status: '010000fb000000000000000000000000',
      location: 'GPS',
      acc: '1',
      acc_seconds: 335,
      voice_status: -1,
      voice_gid: 0 } ] ]`

showing that it's working
how can I make this code into an asynchronous WebSocket that continuously gets that data, then stores it in MongoDB with given fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found a solution, the best(in my opinion) way is to use `setInterval()` function, put the HTTP request inside the function to set how many times per unit time you want to insert in the db, then from there mongodb accepts objects by default, so if you return an object to mongodb is will save it for you, here's the code

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gpsapp2', function(err,client){
if(err) return console.log(err)
db = client.db('gpsapp2')
let counter =0
 setInterval(()=>{
        http.get(_url2, res =>{
        let body='';

        res.on("data", data =>{
                body+=data;
            })
        res.on("end",()=>{
            body = JSON.parse(body);

            //console.log(counter++,'Records inserteerd')
            db.collection('gpsdata').save(body.data[0]);

        })
    })


},1000);
```

http.get from the url, parse the body then save to collection. dont forget the API call is asynchronous so any call for the data outside `res.on('end')` will get empty or undefined results.

hope this helps somebody.